# Why is SliverFillRemaining expanding too much?

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, flutter-sliverappbar

I'm trying to make a SliverAppBar that reacts to its height, showing different things depending if it's expanded or not.

I've based it on https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-sliverappbar-snap-those-headers-544e097248c0, but I'm having an issue:

The empty space at the end of the list is way too long.

Removing SliverFillRemaining is not necessary if the number of items is high, but changing the `numberOfItems`  to e.g. 3 items (instead of 30), the SliverFillRemaining is necessary.

Check out this dartpad for the code: https://dartpad.dev/2c434ddf2d4d1e87bd4b421f0a673c2d

```
      CustomScrollView(
        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: _controller,
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
            stretch: true,
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            flexibleSpace: Header(
              maxHeight: maxHeight,
              minHeight: minHeight,
            ),
            collapsedHeight: minimizedHeight,
            expandedHeight: maxHeight - MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) {
                return _buildCard(index);
              },
              childCount: numberOfItems,
            ),
          ),
          SliverFillRemaining(
              hasScrollBody: true), // ** <-- this will add space, but too much **
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you are just adding a certain height of space, i suggest you use SliverToBoxAdapter:

```
SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: SizedBox(
    height: 50,
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this solution since I couldn't get it working with SliverFillRemaining

Comment: `SliverFillRemaining` looks absolutely pointless. It tries to fill the entire screen, I can't see where it can come in handy. With `hasScrollBody: false` it behaves like a regular SliverToBoxAdapter.

Answer (score 4):

make the hasScrollBody value to be false
like this:

```
     SliverFillRemaining(
        hasScrollBody: false
     ),
```

Answer (score 0):

[This Package](https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_fill_remaining_box_adapter) does exactly what you are expecting, I've been trying for days now,and finally used this, Its works the same way as the SliverToBoxAdapter but extends enough and does not cause over scroll

```
  CustomScrollView(
    physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    controller: _controller,
    slivers: [
      SliverAppBar(
        pinned: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
        stretch: true,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        flexibleSpace: Header(
          maxHeight: maxHeight,
          minHeight: minHeight,
        ),
        collapsedHeight: minimizedHeight,
        expandedHeight: maxHeight - MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
      ),
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (context, index) {
            return _buildCard(index);
          },
          childCount: numberOfItems,
        ),
      ),
      SliverFillRemainingBoxAdapter(
          child: // Your content goes here), 
    ],
  ),
```